# NodeJS + Request REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, api, request

I have the following code an i try to connect to a server and get a json response from the server but somthing is wrong becouse i get this error: error null 401. Can you please help me to identify the error on this code or to find what is missing. Thank you!

```
var request = require('request');


var apiurl = "externalserverurl:6080";
var options = {
  "regid" : "username",
  "password" : "password",
  "uri" : apiurl,
  "registrar_domain" : "mydomain.com",
  "lang" : "en",
  json: true,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log('body:', body);
  } else {
    console.log('error', error, response && response.statusCode);
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Comment: https://httpstatuses.com/401, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401

The 401 error suggests you are making a request that is unauthorized. I can see from your code you are missing an authentication header.

Comment: Thank you. How can i set the authentication header?Tried like this but same error:    var auth = Buffer.from("username" + ':' + "password").toString('base64'); and headers: {
  'Authorization': auth,
}

Comment: Authentication depends on the api. So you should check externalserverurl:6080 documentation for the authentecation mechanism. It could be a token created when logged in, saved in a cookie or in the local memory that should be set in the header.

Answer (score 0):

As @kay already mentioned, errorcode 401 means that your request is unauthorized. Given that there are a lot of different possible authentication methods (basic auth, digest auth, OAuth, you name it), you should refer to your target server and clarify which auth method you should use before trying to actually modify your code.

You could also check the response body, it could contain some hints about what exactly the server expects but doesn't receive.

Comment: How can i add the HTTP Digest Authentication for my example? Thank you!